# Share .Net libraries with GO

Tags: c#, .net, go, pinvoke, shared-memory

I'm looking for a way to write a GO application that use a .NET UI. Or the other way around, a .Net application that calls into a GO library.

Is there anyway to P'Invoke GO, or ".Net'Invoke" from GO?

If not, what is the best performing alternative? The best idea I have right now is RPC.

Comment: I think it's difficult to impossible. cgo can call into C (and C++ in right circumstances), but not .NET. There are things like https://github.com/niemeyer/qml that do run on Windows, and bindings to different GUI libraries listed at http://go-lang.cat-v.org/library-bindings.

Comment: For a wild alternative approach, Go's good for and often used for servers; you could have a .NET client that starts and connects to a local Go server that does the work on the backend.

Comment: @twotwotwo That's likely what I'll end up doing if it doesn't look like there is a better way.

Comment: if you want to build windows gui, there is also https://github.com/lxn/walk

Comment: If cgo can call C, then it can call into .net. It can call COM for instance. Or you can make a C++/CLI mixed mode DLL that can be treated as a native DLL from the outside. Or you can use UnmanagedExports.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to host a .NET CLR in-process. You could in theory write a DLL callable from C, which could host such a CLR.

e.g. [This example project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppHostCLR-e6581ee0#content) demonstrates creating a CLR inside of a C++ application.

If you bundle together the required state (e.g. `ICLRRuntimeInfo` et al.) into a struct, you should be able to call the equivalents from a DLL written in C, and return a 'handle' or some such other wrapper to your Go application.

What is not entirely clear from the documentation is

- Whether it's legal for an assembly loaded in another process to perform these calls (vs. the process itself)
- Whether C++ is mandatory instead of C (doesn't seem to be the case, but I have not attempted the above and there are some 'suspicious' declarations in some of the example code w.r.t vanilla C)